# Good books in inorganic chemistry?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, books

I would like you to reccomend me a book (books) in inorganic chemistry , with good explanations , problems and solutions. Actually, i want to study it profoundly, but my theory isn't good enough.

Answer (score 0):

I think J.D Lee is good book to get a Good grip on  concepts Of inorganic chemistry.(Its the type of book which is recognized by the name of its Author)